# biblatex-chicago: translationas does not work without translator name

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

**Edited:** title changed to use `translationas` instead of `translatedas`, since the former is the correct name for the relation. I have left the latter in the question.

In my bibliography, I want to inform readers of the English translation of a work I cite. If I just use the `translatedas` relation to link the two entries, nothing is printed between them:

[image: default entry]

This seems likely to confuse readers, as well as not corresponding to the *Manual* (16th ed., 14.109). So I want to add "translated as" before the data for the translation. I can do that by defining the bibliography string `translatedas`, which works fine with `verbose-ibid`, but with `biblatex-chicago` it produces two spurious commas and drops some punctuation and spacing between elements:

[image: entry with translatedas defined]

The problem depends on the lack of a translator name. Furet's book actually does have a translator, and if her name is included in the entry then all goes well. However, in my case, the translation I want to cite is anonymous. How can I add a relation to an anonymous translation?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\NewBibliographyString{translatedas}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{translatedas = {translated as}}
\nocite{furet:related} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{furet:passing:eng,
      Author = {Furet, François},
      Location = {Chicago},
      Publisher = {University of Chicago Press},
      Title = {The Passing of an Illusion},
      Year = {1999}
    }

    @book{furet:related,
      Author = {Furet, François},
      Location = {Paris},
      Publisher = {Éditions Robert Laffont},
      Related = {furet:passing:eng},
      Relatedtype = {translatedas},
      Title = {Le passé d'une illusion},
      Year = {1995}
    }

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example below uses the pre-defined `relatedtype`/bibstring `translationas`, but the same could be done for a new `translatedas`.

Apparently, the default `related` driver of `biblatex-chicago` does not give good results in your case (I did not investigate in depth why the punctuation is missing), but we can adapt `related:bytranslator` a bit and just throw out the explicit printing of the translator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{related:translationas}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \usebibmacro{at+every+item}%
    \renewbibmacro*{name:hook}[1]{%
      \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}%
        {\begingroup
         \mkrelatedstring%
         \lbx@initnamehook{#1}%
         \endgroup}%
        {}}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:origfull}}}%
\makeatother

\nocite{furet:related} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{furet:passing:eng,
  Author    = {Furet, François},
  Location  = {Chicago},
  Publisher = {University of Chicago Press},
  Title     = {The Passing of an Illusion},
  Year      = {1999},
}
@book{furet:related,
  Author      = {Furet, François},
  Location    = {Paris},
  Publisher   = {Éditions Robert Laffont},
  Related     = {furet:passing:eng},
  Relatedtype = {translationas},
  Title       = {Le passé d'une illusion},
  Year        = {1995},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Furet, François. Le passé d’une illusion. Paris: Éditions Robert Laffont, 1995. Translated as The Passing of an Illusion (Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 1999).]

That said, if there is a `translator` in the `related` work it usually gives much nicer results to use the `relatedtype` `bytranslator` instead of `translationas`.